# To check if last name is part of first name

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on Data standardization rules, and one of the rules says, "If the last name is part of first name, then remove the last name from first name". 
my Query- how do i check if first name column has the last name in it using oracle sql developer?

I tried using :

```
select fst_nm, lst_nm from emp where fst_nm = fst_nm || lst_nm  ;
```

but this query returns '0' results.

Also, I tried another query:

```
select fst_nm, lst_nm, regexp_substr(fst_nm, '[^ ]+',1,1) from emp ;
```

I tried using the below query

```
select fst_nm, lst_nm from emp where fst_nm = fst_nm || lst_nm  ;
```

but this query returns nothing, I mean '0' results.

Also, I tried another query:

```
select fst_nm, lst_nm, regexp_substr(fst_nm, '[^ ]+',1,1) from emp ;
```

expected result is:

```
fst_nm = john smith ;
lst_nm = smith
```

Actual result showing up is :

```
fst_nm = john ;  
lst_nm = smith
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do a blanket replace on the entire table:

```
UPDATE emp
SET fst_nm = REPLACE(fst_nm, lst_nm, '');
```

The reason this should work is that for those records where the last name does *not* appear as part of the first name, the replace would have no effect.  Otherwise, the last name would be stripped from the first name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic

select length('saurabh rai'),instr('saurabh rai',' '),case when  length('saurabh rai') > instr('saurabh rai',' ') then substr('saurabh',1,instr('saurabh rai',' ')-1) else 'saurabh rai' end as a from dual;

Update emp set fst_nm=(Case when length(fst_nm) > instr(fst_nm, ' ') then substr(fst_nm,1,instr(fst_nm,' ')-1) else fst_nm end);